# Windows 10 AppLocker AppID issue

Tags: windows-10

Trying to enable AppLocker on Win 10 Enterprise. Have AppID and AppIDSVC enabled (automatic start), everything looks good. Then when I start inserting policy rules into AppLocker (specifically the DLL rules), I get an error log in Event Viewer stating:

AppID policy conversion failed. Status Access is denied User: SYSTEM

And that's basically all the info I get. Why is it trying to convert the policy? Where is this policy? How do I give the system access?

If I ignore this error (don't unless you're working on a clean machine with recent restore points), and I continue to configure AppLocker, it works. For that session. When I reboot, after the bios loads, the OS does not, and I get a grey screen and need to restore. This is obviously not good, and I have been working around the clock trying to fix it. I have found nothing that helps on the internet thus far.

Any insight & advice would be greatly appreciated.